# Toruble with coding a bar graph with Xs on eclipse

Tags: java

Friendly Hal's Used Cars has four salespeople named Pam, Leo, Kim, and Bob. Accept values for the number of cars sold by each salesperson in a month. Also create a bar chart that illustrates sales.

Honestly have not tried anything. I am new to java and do not know how to make a bar graph with only an X representing the data input.

```
public class BarGraph extends Applet implements ActionListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

// Declare Objects
Label lblPam = new Label("Pam");
Label lblLeo = new Label("Leo");
Label lblKim = new Label("Kim");
Label lblBob = new Label("Bob");
TextField txtPam = new TextField(5);
TextField txtLeo = new TextField(5);
TextField txtKim = new TextField(5);
TextField txtBob = new TextField(5);
TextArea txaGraph = new TextArea(15, 20);

Button btnSubmit = new Button("Submit");

// Variables 
private static int intCount;
private static int intSales;

public void init()
{
    // Main Method
    DesignLayout();
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(this);
}


private void DesignLayout() {
    // Sets the Layout Manager
    GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    setLayout (gridbag);
    constraints.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

    // Row 1, Column 1 Label
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(lblPam, constraints);
    add(lblPam);

    // Row 1, Column 2 Label
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(lblLeo, constraints);
    add(lblLeo);

    // Row 1, Column 3 Label
    constraints.gridx = 3;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(lblKim, constraints);
    add(lblKim);

    // Row 1, Column 4 Label
    constraints.gridx = 4;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(lblBob, constraints);
    add(lblBob);

    // Row 2, Column 1 TextField
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txtPam, constraints);
    add(txtPam);

    // Row 2, Column 2 TextField
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txtLeo, constraints);
    add(txtLeo);

    // Row 2, Column 3 TextField
    constraints.gridx = 3;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txtKim, constraints);
    add(txtKim);

    // Row 2, Column 1 TextField
    constraints.gridx = 4;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txtBob, constraints);
    add(txtBob);

    // Row 3, Column 1 Button
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 4;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(btnSubmit, constraints);
    add(btnSubmit);

    // Row 3, Column 2 TextArea
    constraints.gridx = 2;
    constraints.gridy = 4;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txaGraph, constraints);
    add(txaGraph);
}



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Checks for submit button click

    if (e.getSource() == btnSubmit)
    {
        PerformForLoop(intSales);
    }


}


private void PerformForLoop(int intSales2) {
    // Puts number into graph 

    intCount = 0;
    intSales = 0;

    this.txaGraph.setText("");

    for (intCount = 1; )
```

Comment: When a user types in sales for each person the results will be displayed in a TextArea bar graph with only an X representing the number put in. This is in eclipse and should be in a for loop.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Please provide [minimal reproducible example!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852)